# I want to show the background image only at the left and right edge of the screen

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I have this container that contain an image but it took all of the background screen. I want to show it only at the right and left edge of the screen like 20% of the right and left screen is reserved for image. This is my code :

```css
.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML here, please -->
```

Comment: a gradient could partially hide it, but you don't say how much of the sides should be shown, or how much of the center should be hidden . Please clarify your question to get help.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to include HTML along with your styles in a demo snippet using the editor. Also explain better what you're trying to accomplish. Your description is a bit confusing.

Comment: then, here is the idea of the gradient, that can even be translucent : https://jsfiddle.net/upqacwo8/

Answer (score 1):

Below is the html needed to produce the desired effect (from what I can understand based on the question description). You can see that the image provided pops through 20% on both the right and the left edges of the screen, while leaving the content inside the container div which I added visible.

```css
.container {
          flex: 1;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          margin-top: 20px;
          background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
          /*new container css*/
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center
        }

        .container div {
          background: white;
          width: 60%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>
<h2>Example Content</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

If you provide the html you are aiming to use, the answer provided can be more catered to your specific needs.